# How to access Windows.Services.Store from Java application

Tags: java, windows, store

We have a Java application that we publish in the Windows Store.  We would like to implement in-app purchases, for which we need to use the Windows.Services.Store API.

How can we access the Windows.Services.Store API from Java?

Comment: Check this https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-dev-docs/blob/docs/windows-apps-src/monetize/java-code-examples-for-the-windows-store-submission-api.md

Comment: This link explains how to work with the Windows Store to automatically submit new products and packages.  This is not what we're looking for, we need to be able to verify that a product has been purchased, or that an in-app purchase has been made for the app.